# Can I create a Documents directory in Xcode, and put files in it for my iOS app through the UI. If so, how?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode11, nsdocumentdirectory

I need to read/write a tiny amount of info for data persistence in an iOS app.  I am using plists and understand that I can read, but not write to the bundle.  If I create the plist files initially at development time, how can I place the plists in the "Documents" area of my app so that they are later writable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

As you say, an iOS app's bundle is not writable, but it is readable.

Further, an app's documents directory doesn't exist until the app is run (on the user's target device) for the first time. Thus, you can't build your app's documents directory at compile-time, nor can you submit an app to the app store with a prepopulated Documents directory. (It would be nice if Apple gave us the ability to provide a "seed" documents directory that got **moved** to the documents directory at first launch, but they do not provide that facility -- at least not that I'm aware of.)

What you **can** do is to create a sub-directory of your bundle that contains a set of files that you want to place in the app's documents directory.

On launch, check a "hasBeenInstalled" flag in `UserDefaults`. If it's true, do nothing. if it's false, use the file manager to copy files from your app's bundle into the app's documents directory, then write `hasBeenInstalled=true` to `UserDefaults`.

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactly what I needed to know and I now understand why there is a lot of information about how to copy to Documents directory.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. If my answer has addressed your question then you should accept it. (That is a very strong norm for this board.) Once you have enough reputation, you should also consider up-voting helpful answers. (up-voting is optional, but accepting the first correct answer is pretty much a requirement.)